# How do I reset all user passwords to 123 with drush or SQL?

Tags: 7, drush

For testing purposes I like to reset all user passwords to 123.

Is this possible in Drush or SQL?
I guess the query will be someting like this but cannot find the exact yourhash:

```
UPDATE `<mydatabase>`.`users` SET `pass` = '<yourhash>' ;
```

Can I run the final query with drush?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using Drush, with following steps ([e.g.](https://randyfay.com/content/resetting-drupal-passwords-drupal-7-drush-or-without)):

1.Generate a password hash using following command:

```
$ cd [/var/www/html/drupal7]
$ php scripts/password-hash.sh '123'
```

2.Now run following drush command:

```
$ drush sql-cli
mysql > UPDATE users SET `pass` = 'pasted_big_hash_from_above' WHERE uid > 1;
```

Update `pasted_big_hash_from_above` with password hash generated using `php` command in step #1.

Answer (score -2):

Solved.

Query can be done in Drush with:

```
drush sql-query UPDATE `users` SET `pass` = '$S$DM7xrCBIKOrShBhgb1eUkpPlnnAq36QKIlMfdkKhvaTS2iv0PuJ3'
```

Comment: This hash corresponds to 123 for the specific site only.